# How do you solve $T = r\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^k\right)$ for $r$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve $T = r\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^k\right)$ for $r$ in-terms of $T$ and $k$?

Comment: Well, if $r$ is positive, I believe the logarithmic function will help you, since $ln(xy)=lnx+lny$ and $lnx^y=ylnx$. Make the appropriate calculations carefully..

Comment: Are you expecting an answer in elementary terms?  (If so, you will be disappointed.)  How [far from elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Comparison_of_different_classes_of_expressions) would be suitable?

Comment: @EricTowers How did you figure out that there is no closed-form answer?

Comment: There's no closed formula for the solution of $P(x)=0$ when $P$ is a polynomial of degree $\ge 5$

Comment: @Sam Sorry, could you please explain why the RHS is a polynomial in $r$? There is an $r$ term and also a $\frac{1}{1+r}$ term.

Comment: @yonatano : Is $k$ allowed to be, for a semi-random example, four?  Then set $k = 4$, clear denominators, and realize you have a degree five polynomial in $r$.  As a *single case*, you have a notoriously infeasible problem.  Maybe if we pick a value of $T$?  Set $T = 1$.  Your polynomial is $r^5 - 3r^4 - 2 r^3 + 2 r^2 + 4r + 1$, which does not have roots expressible as radicals.  So a single case of a single case has left the realm of elementary terms; the situation won't improve more generally.

Comment: @yonatano It becomes a polynomial by multiplying by $(1+r)^k$ on both sides

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve for $r$ the equation$$T = r\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^k\right)$$ for $T$ and $k$ given.

As in finance calculations, let us suppose that $r \ll 1$. Expanding the rhs as a Taylor series, we should have
$$k r^2-\frac{k (k+1)}{2}  r^3+\frac{k (k+1) (k+2)}{6}  r^4-\frac{k (k+1)
   (k+2) (k+3)}{24}  r^5+\frac{k (k+1) (k+2) (k+3) (k+4)}{120}  r^6+O\left(r^7\right)$$

No, using series reversion would give, as an *aproximation*,
$$r=t+\frac{k+1}{4}  t^2+\frac{(k+1) (7 k-1)}{96} t^3+\frac{k(k+1)(k-1)}{48}
    t^4+$$ $$\frac{(k+1) \left(491 k^3-1391 k^2+481 k+59\right)}{92160}t^5+O\left(t^6\right)$$ where $t=\sqrt{\frac T k}$.

To check how good or bad is this *approximation*, let us fix $k=100$. Give $r$ a value and compute $T$ and, using the formula, compute the predicted value of $r$.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
r_{\text{given}} & r_{\text{predicted}}\\
 0.005 & 0.00499992749 \\
 0.010 & 0.00999778967 \\
 0.015 & 0.01498820780 \\
 0.020 & 0.01997053282 \\
 0.025 & 0.02495643640 \\
 0.030 & 0.02996965261 \\
 0.035 & 0.03504122942 \\
 0.040 & 0.04020442838 \\
 0.045 & 0.04549110285 \\
 0.050 & 0.05092975519
\end{array}
\right)$$ For sure, we could do better using more terms in the initial Taylor expansion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If possible could you please add some more detail in the “series reversion” step? I don’t understand how you solved for $r$ there. Thanks!

Comment: @yonatano. Have a look at   https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html